# Is it possible to block out reality completely?

Tags: psychology

Is it possible for an individual to block out all reality and see objects, colors and hear voices and sounds that are non-existent non-stop?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Seeing objects, colors, hearing voices and sounds are electrical impulses translated by our sensorial organs and sent to the brain. There are cases of blind people which can "see" (feel?) a whole load of abstract images, and [are actually bothered by it](http://www.thebeaconreview.com/entertainment/do-blind-men-and-women-actually-knowledge-full-darkness-h6647.html).

A person could have no sensing organs and still have electrical impulses by means of [artificial brain stimulus](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3786182/), or due to a neurological damage; [tinnitus](http://www.nidcd.nih.gov/health/hearing/pages/tinnitus.aspx) comes to mind (no pun intended).

> When TMS [transcranial magnetic stimulation] is applied with a single pulse to motor or sensory cortex, it is possible to evoke a motor or sensory response. When the sensory cortex is visual cortex, the response is a phosphene.4 Phosphenes are the sensation of light in the absence of visual stimulation.

Answer (score 0):

1. We do this with dreams. Lucid dreaming allows us to modify what we experience.
2. This is the stock in trade of stage hypnotists. They induce a false or partially false reality in which the subject experiences non-real people, objects and sensations. Self-hypnosis is possible.
3. This happens with hallucinogens, e.g. peyote.